# Get hidden field value from html

Tags: java, html

I'm writing a program that gets html page and extracts value from hidden field. But when in response I don't have this field, so i can't extract value from it.

This is one part of html:

```
<form class="important" method="post" action="/do">
    <button class="important" type="submit">do</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="123" name="abc">
</form>
```

Here's how I extract:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/do");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

The result I get is

```
<form class="important" method="post" action="/do">
    <button class="important" type="submit">do</button>        
</form>
```

As you can see, I can't extract data from this field.
Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Is the hidden field created using client side script?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. Is there any other info I might provide?

Comment: Your server must not be sending what you think it is.

Comment: I think you'd have to share whatever code is generating the HTML `<input type="hidden" value="123" name="abc">` - for some reason, it shows up with some requests and not others.

Comment: I'm testing some functionality of site and don't have access to the source code itself.
I see this field in fireBug in FF, but don't have it in java application. And I use the same GET request as I saw in firebug.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to look at the *entire* HTTP GET request.  There must be *some* difference in the HTTP VERB, URL, headers, cookies, etc.

Comment: Even there I don't see that field. Any suggestions where I should search where this field is created? Is it possible that there is no way I could get this field, or should I look closer at javascript(if it's there)?

Comment: Yea I'm not following.  When *do* you see this field?

Comment: I see this field ONLY in FireBug and I see value from this field in POST request.

Comment: If you don't see it in *View Page Source*, then I'm pretty certain that it's added with JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a closer look at js. Thank you. If you write it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two possibilities for this.

**1) The hidden field only shows up for certain HTTP requests.**

This means the server will only *render* that tag if certain criteria are true.  For example, maybe the HTTP VERB must be POST, a certain HTTP Header must exist, a certain URL parameter must be present, or a certain cookie value must be provided.  If you cannot look at the server code, the easiest way to diagnose this would be using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).  This allows you to look at the raw HTTP Request that causes the desired behavior, then attempt to replicate the request using Java.

**2) The server is not generating the hidden field at all.**

This means the HTML content in question is not being generated from the server *ever*.  The easiest way to verify this is by looking at the HTML source using *Right Click->View Page Source* in the browser.  This will include *only* HTML content rendered by the server.  If the HTML code in question is not present, it's a pretty strong indication the code might have been generated dynamically using JavaScript.  Another way to confirm this would be to disable JavaScript and see if the code is still present in the DOM explorer.  If this is the case, it *also* means the information required by the client to *generate* the hidden input is *somewhere* on the page.  You would then be able to parse the HTML and get at this information another way, in essence re-writing the client side code that generated the hidden input in the first place.